# Invalid type argument of '->' (have unsigned int) error

Tags: c, struct, casting

I defined a macro function in c as

```
#define PortA_Clk_En()     RCC->AHB1ENR |= (1 << 0)
```

But when I call the macro function inside the program it gives the following error

> Invalid type argument of '->' (have unsigned int)

RCC is type casted as

```
#define base_addr    0x20097654
#define RCC     (Reg_t*)base_addr
```

Where `Reg_t` is

```
typedef struct{
    uint32_t AHB1ENR;
}Reg_t;
```

I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: Add parentheses to your macro definition. Otherwise you'll have problems with operator precedence after the macro expansion.

Comment: It doesn't affect the problem, but why is the macro defined as a function when it doesn't have any parameters?

Comment: I'm learning embedded systems programming from a public playlist, so I am only following instructions. After adding parantheses, the question was solved. I want to hang myself now

Comment: @Zzz - You might want to get a different playlist instead. Or read a book! About 90% of Youtube "tutorials" are made by people who know less than you do. Seriously,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
RCC->AHB1ENR
```

Will expand to this:

```
(Reg_t*)base_addr->AHB1ENR
```

And since the `->` operator has higher precedence than the typecast operator, it parses as this:

```
(Reg_t*)(base_addr->AHB1ENR)
```

And since `base_addr` isn't a pointer to a struct or union, you get the error.

You need to add parenthesis to your `#define` so things are grouped the way you want:

```
#define RCC     ((Reg_t*)base_addr)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
#define PortA_Clk_En()     (RCC)->AHB1ENR |= (1 << 0)
```

or, even better (THX user [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar)!)

```
#define PortA_Clk_En()     ((RCC)->AHB1ENR |= (1 << 0))
```

to enforce necessary semantics

```
((Reg_t*)base_addr)->AHB1ENR |= (1 << 0)
```

or full parenthesising

```
(((Reg_t*)base_addr)->AHB1ENR |= (1 << 0))
```

instead of

```
(Reg_t*)base_addr->AHB1ENR |= (1 << 0)
```

as it is now.

Comment: Also put parentheses around the whole expansion.

Comment: @Barmar Added. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you miss parenthesises

```
#define PortA_Clk_En()     RCC->AHB1ENR |= (1 << 0)
#define base_addr    0x20097654
#define RCC     ((Reg_t*)base_addr)

typedef struct{
    uint32_t AHB1ENR;
}Reg_t;
```